# HtmlWebPackPlugin select js and css to inject

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

Got 2 entry points in my project: *login* and *index*.
I'd like to generate 2 html files with following injection content:
index.html: index.hash.js + index.hash.css
login.html: login.hash.js + login.hash.css

Got the following webpack config:

```
module.exports = (env, options) => {
    let development = options.mode !== 'production';

    const config = {
        entry: {
            login: ['./src/Login/index.js'],
            index: ['./src/Main/index.js'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
        },
        devServer: {
            overlay: true,
            open: 'login.html',
        },
        module: {
            // too many rows here
        },
        plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[hash:8].css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/login.html',
            filename: 'login.html',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
        ],
        devtool: development ? 'source-map' : false,
    };

    return config;
};
```

As result, I have 2 html files, that contains 2 same injected scriptes and stylesheets (index.hash.js, index.hash.css, login.hash.js and login.hash.css in each html file).

How to choose what script to inject? Could anyone share a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: RESOLVED: added extra parameter excludeChunks: ['index'] in login config and excludeChunks: ['login'] in index config of HtmlWebpackPlugin.